# Create serial queue for network calls generated by push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3, queue, cloudkit

I am receiving up to four push notifications for each event I am subscribed to.  I have gone through everything related to my CloudKit subscriptions and notification registry and I am convinced this is an Apple problem.  I have instead turned my attention toward correctly processing the notifications no matter how many I receive.  Here is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```
func recievePrivatePush(_ pushInfo: [String:NSObject], completion: @escaping ()->Void) {

    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: pushInfo)
    let alertBody = notification.alertBody

    if let queryNotification = notification as? CKQueryNotification {
        let recordID = queryNotification.recordID
        guard let body = queryNotification.alertBody else {
            return
        }

        if recordID != nil {
            switch body {
            case "Notification Type":
                let id = queryNotification.recordID
                switch queryNotification.queryNotificationReason {
                case .recordCreated:
                    DataCoordinatorInterface.sharedInstance.fetchDataItem(id!.recordName, completion: {
                        //
                    })
                    break

                default:
                    break
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The fetching code looks something like this:

```
func fetchDataItem(_ id: String, completion: @escaping ()-> Void) {

    if entityExistsInCoreData(id) {return}


    let db = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: id)
    db.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, error) in
        if let topic = record {
            //Here I create and save the object to core data.
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

All of my code works, the problem I am having is that when I receive multiple notifications, multiple fetch requests are started before the first core data entity is created, resulting in redundant core data objects.

What I would like to do is find a way to add the fetch requests to a serial queue so they are processed one at a time.  I can put my request calls in a serial queue, but the callbacks always run asynchronously, so multiple fetch requests are still make before the first data object is persisted.

I have tried using semaphores and dispatch groups with a pattern that looks like this:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)    

func recievePrivatePush(_ pushInfo: [String:NSObject], completion: @escaping ()->Void) {

    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: pushInfo)
    let alertBody = notification.alertBody

    if let queryNotification = notification as? CKQueryNotification {
        let recordID = queryNotification.recordID
        guard let body = queryNotification.alertBody else {
            return
        }

        if recordID != nil {
            switch body {
            case "Notification Type":
                let id = queryNotification.recordID
                switch queryNotification.queryNotificationReason {
                case .recordCreated:
                    DataCoordinatorInterface.sharedInstance.fetchDataItem(id!.recordName, completion: {
                        semaphore.signal()
                    })
                    break

                default:
                    break
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Once the above function is called for the second time, and semaphore.wait is called, the execution of the first network request pauses, resulting in a frozen app.

Again, what I would like to accomplish it adding the asynchronous network requests to a queue so that they are made only one at a time i.e. the first network call is completed before the second request is started.

Comment: Carl, Unsure if I have clearly understood the issue, but here a is an alternative approach to dealing with multiple [duplicate] notifications. It is very straight forward, simply use a dictionary to save the notifications as they come in so that you can recognize duplicates easily. That way even if you get a second or third or more notification of the same event, it won't matter. You just check your dictionary and throw away the duplicate.

Comment: The problem is still that the notifications arrive nearly simultaneously and are processed by the app delegate in parallel. I will get a few false positives before there is time to add a key value pair to the dictionary and check against it.

Answer (score 0):

Carl,

Perhaps you'll find your solutions with dispatch groups, a few key expressions to look into.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
```

... code ...

```
group.leave
group.wait()
```

I use them to limit the number of http requests I send out in a batch, to wait for the response. Perhaps you could use them together with the suggestion in my comment. Watch this video too, dispatch groups in here, I think more.

```
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have found the dispatch groups and semaphores were not well suited for this particular problem.  I took some advice from your earlier comment.  What I ended up doing to creating a serial queue to manage access to an array instead of actually making requests and I turns out to work well.  Thanks for the help!  I'll updated my question with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

These simple classes helped me solve the problem.

```
class PushQueue {

internal var pushArray: Array<String> = [String]()
internal let pushQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.pushNotifications")

public func addPush(_ push: Push) {
    pushQueue.sync {
        if pushArray.contains(push.id) {
            return
        } else {
            pushArray.append(push.id)
            processNotification(push: push)
        }
    }
}

internal func processNotification(push: Push) {
    PushInterface.sharedInstance.recievePrivatePush(push.userInfo as! [String: NSObject])
}

}


class CKPush: Equatable {

init(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    let ck = userInfo["ck"] as? NSDictionary
    let id = ck?["nid"] as? String
    self.id = id!
    self.userInfo = userInfo
}

var id: String
var userInfo: [AnyHashable:Any]

public static func ==(lhs: CKPush, rhs: CKPush) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id ? true : false
}

}
```

Please ignore the sloppy force unwraps.  They need to be cleaned up.